# PendingIntent BroadcastReceiver getting null extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

When using `PendingIntent` we should make it unique (depending on our use case) by assigning a diferent action with `setAction` or `setData` since the system reuses `Intents` and compares them using `Intent.filterEquals` which does **not** compare the intent extras, however for the very first `Intent` and in any subsequent `Intents` im receiving in my `BroadcastReceiver` im getting the extras set to null, unless off course i uncomment the line setting the intent `data` uri is this the expected behaviour and if so is it documented somewhere or is this a bug ?

```
 public static void setOutgoingNotification(Context context,
                                           CharSequence contentTitle,
                                           CharSequence contentText,
                                           boolean available) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setOngoing(true);

    NotificationCompat.Action action;

    Intent availabilityIntent = new Intent(context, AvailabilityReceiver.class);
    availabilityIntent.putExtra(AvailabilityReceiver.EXTRA_AVAILABILITY, !available);
    //availabilityIntent.setData(Uri.parse(availabilityIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

    PendingIntent availabilityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, availabilityIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    if(available){
        action = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_stat_off,
            context.getString(R.string.unavailable),
            availabilityPendingIntent);
    }else {
        action = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_stat_on,
            context.getString(R.string.available),
            availabilityPendingIntent);
    }

    builder.addAction(action);

    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    mgr.notify(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION, builder.build());
}
```